# How to compile a source file with jsoup.jar in classpath?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a problem on executing a compiled file. I compile my `Hello.java` file as

```
javac -cp \mypathto\jsoup.jar Hello.java
```

I can't execute it after, because I got the "undefined class Jsoup" error. I tried with different ways to add classpath but its still the same. Any idea? The `Hello.java`

```
import java.io.File;
import org.jsoup.*;


public class Hello {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        try {
            File input = new File("prove.xml");

            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
//Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();

            Elements descriptions = doc.select("div.details > p.description");

            for (Element element : descriptions) {
                System.out.println(element.ownText());
                System.out.println("--------------");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The "undefined class" is not a runtime error. It's a compiletime error. Your source file is still not compiled. Are you sure that the path to Jsoup JAR file is correct? Do you understand how file system paths work? What operating system are you using and what is the absolute path from the root on to the Jsoup JAR file?

Answer (score -1):

Try using some IDE like eclipse,netbeans,IDEA etc. so that it will be easy to run and debug